# here output not displayed to '#viewbook' from database

Tags: php, ajax

```
<select id="viewbook" ></select>   
            <script type="text/javascript">
function getbook(val){
if( val!==''){ alert(val);}else{alert("no value");}
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"pagination.php",
  data:{category:val},
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){
    $("#viewbook").html(data);
  }
});
```

}

then here variable 'category'gets and passed to 'pagination.php' but no output displayed from database other than "select from here"

```
<?php    
include"connection.inc";

if (!empty($_POST["category"])) {
  $pdt = $_POST['category'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM library_details WHERE bookcategory='$pdt'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $output = '<option value="">Select from  here</option>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $output .= '<option value="' . $row["bookname"] . '">"' . $row["bookname"] . '"</option>';
  }
  echo $output;
}?>
```

Comment: `dataType: 'text'` should be `HTML` or `JSON`

Comment: Hello. You should stop using `mysql_` driver, its deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` instead. Also look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them with prepared statements. Your code is really unsafe and your database could be hacked in a few seconds.

Comment: hence no output gained!!!!

Comment: You should aslo escape vars before passing them to your query.

Comment: what does console.log(data); say in your .js file?

Comment: Change `$output='<optionvalue="'.` to `$output='<option value="'.`

Comment: pls explain????

Comment: Is DB Connection present in your `include"connection.inc";` file? Show **connection.inc** file too.

Comment: yes it is...do u hav any suggestion just go ahead...

Comment: First show what is written in **connection.inc** file

Comment: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING  ^ E_DEPRECATED);

if(!$conn)
{
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="nestsoft_indiaoptions";
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dat=mysql_select_db($db);
}
?>

Comment: Is your database connection working properly? I'm seeing first time any database connection in **.inc** file.

Comment: yes ...i used it in someother pages...pls suggest any solution

Comment: Can u please suggest me an option extend this dependency to another text value

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="viewbook"></select>
```

**Ajax call:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getbook(val){
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'pagination.php',
      dataType : 'html',
      data: {
          category : val
      },
      success : function(data){
          $("#viewbook").html(data);
      },
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          ("#viewbook").html("Error");
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

 if(!empty($_POST["category"])) {
  $pdt = $_POST['category'];
  $sql = "select * from library_details where bookcategory = '$pdt' ";
  $output='';
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $output = '<option value="">Select from  here</option>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    $output .='<option value="'.$row["bookname"].'">'.$row["bookname"].'</option>';
  }
  //echo $row['bookname'];
  echo $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: hence "select from here" displays but none other from database

Comment: here only 1 dropdown showing with'select from here'

Answer (score 0):

Change `dataType: 'text',` to `dataType: 'html',`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function getbook(val){
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"pagination.php",
      data:{category:val},
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){
        $("#viewbook").html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**pagination.php**

**1)** Concatenate the output

**2)** Remove extra `$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);`

**3)** Change `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {` to `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {`

**4)** Change `$output='<optionvalue="'` to `$output .='<option value="'`

**5)** Remove `echo $row['bookname'];`

```
if (!empty($_POST["category"])) {
  $pdt = $_POST['category'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM library_details WHERE bookcategory='$pdt'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $output = '<option value="">Select from  here</option>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $output .= '<option value="' . $row["bookname"] . '">"' . $row["bookname"] . '"</option>';
  }
  echo $output;
}
```

Comment: i just did your suggestion ..hence no output

Comment: Show us where is your #viewcode present in your code @jibinkj

Comment: <select id="viewbook" ></select>

Comment: Please use this code once again and check @jibinkj. I modified few lines of code.

Comment: hence "select from here" displays... but none other from database

Comment: Please paste your code which you tried just now. Edit your question with your tried code @jibinkj

Comment: How much time you will take to edit your question with tried code @jibinkj? Already 6 minutes over